# Snap to scroll in scroll stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, window

Find below image reference:

[image]

What I want exactly is when only one section (section4) comes in window view around 40% - 80%. On `scroll` stop the section4 should auto scroll to fit on `window`.

Here, The basic **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vy72xqwx/1/)** without any script.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.sections {
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#section2 {
  background: #ccc;
}
#section3 {
  background: #9c0;
}
#section4 {
  background: #999;
}
#section4 {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="sections" id="section1"></div>
<div class="sections" id="section2"></div>
<div class="sections" id="section3"></div>
<div class="sections" id="section4"></div>
<div class="sections" id="section5"></div>
```

I have tried `jquery visible` plugin but it didn't help. So I have put commented one.

```
/*
var ww = $(window).width();
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($('#section3').visible(true)) {
    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: $('#section4').offset().top});
  }else if($('#section5').visible(true)) {
  $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: $('#section4').offset().top});    
  }
});
*/
```

Comment: Also possible with fullPage.js as seen [in this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html#secondPage).

Comment: Fullpage.js is very good but when you want all sections snap to scroll. But when it comes to only one section snap to scroll. It becomes little complicated with fullpage.js. I have tried previously but stuck many times.

Comment: Have you tried using the function [`setFitToSection`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#setfittosectionboolean) to enable or disable it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use script to compare the `scrollTop` of the screen with the `offset().top` and the `height` of the `section`.

Note that `ratio` determines how much the element is seen on the screen (greater that 0.6 is used to determine if more than 60% of the `section` is visible on screen).

See demo below with comments inline:

```js
/*debouce (courtesy:underscore.js)*/
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};

// scroll listener
$(window).scroll(debounce(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  // change this to '.sections' if you want the effect for all sections
  $('#section4').each(function() {
    var top_of_element = $(this).offset().top;
    var bottom_of_element = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
    var bottom_of_screen = $window.scrollTop() + $window.height();
    var top_of_screen = $window.scrollTop();
    var height_of_element = $(this).outerHeight();

    // if element below top of screen
    if (top_of_element > top_of_screen && bottom_of_screen < bottom_of_element) {
      var ratio = (bottom_of_screen - top_of_element) / height_of_element;
      if (ratio > 0.6) {
        // animate by scrolling up
        $('body, html').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        });
      }

    }
    // if element above top of screen
    else if (bottom_of_element > top_of_screen && bottom_of_screen > bottom_of_element) {
      var ratio = (bottom_of_element - top_of_screen) / height_of_element;
      if (ratio > 0.6) {
        // animate by scrolling down
        $('body, html').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        });
      }
    }
  });
}, 250));
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.sections {
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#section2 {
  background: #ccc;
}
#section3 {
  background: #9c0;
}
#section4 {
  background: #999;
}
#section4 {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sections" id="section1"></div>
<div class="sections" id="section2"></div>
<div class="sections" id="section3"></div>
<div class="sections" id="section4"></div>
<div class="sections" id="section5"></div>
```